# how to do a line break in Bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I do a line break in bootstrap?, I could just use `<br>` but I would like to know if I can do this with boostrap and avoid insert `<br>` in my code.

I would like a empty space beetween the button and **col-md-12**

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y9mznrna/

css:

```
.col-md-8 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.col-md-4 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <h2>test</h2>
  <div class="headline-date">Tuesday
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
      <i class="fa fa-user-plus " aria-hidden="true"></i>Call
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <!-- members table -->
    <div class="col-md-8">
      1
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      2
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: put empty div `<div style="height: 10px;"></div>` after the button

Comment: I would clear the float and give a margin to the button.

Comment: custom css is the only solution for bootstrap 3

Comment: As far as I am looking at the bootstrap class definations, even they have used custom class to give bottom padding/margin.

Reference to bootstrap [example](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the button should be inside it's own row. Right now you just have an orphaned `col-xs-12` which violates the Bootstrap standards. So doing that will separate them better. After that you need some margin between them

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <h2>test</h2>
  <div class="headline-date">Tuesday
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
      <i class="fa fa-user-plus " aria-hidden="true"></i>Call
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 ">
    <!-- members table -->
    <div class="col-md-8">
      1
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      2
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And styling:

```
.col-md-8 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.col-md-4 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.headline-date { 
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/y9mznrna/1/

Answer (score 3):

You can use an empty col with a defined height, like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 bs-linebreak">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bs-linebreak {
  height:10px;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cyo5xbef/2/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the first column in a row like you did at the last content, like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
content
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add a margin-top:10px; in side your button style.

```
<button style="margin-top:10px;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
      <i class="fa fa-user-plus " aria-hidden="true"></i>Call
</button>
```

you can change 10px to anything you like the gap to be